# Setting up 500 error page in XM Cloud Sitecore instance with static html pages

Tags: nextjs, xm-cloud, sxa-jss

I am trying to have setup `500 error` page in `XM Cloud` Sitecore instance.

I have configured "**Server error page link**" in setting item but do not see "**Error Handling**" tab to generate static error pages.
Even if I have static html page I am not able to hit static error page, instead it hit `_error.tsx` page from `next.js` app.
Please let me know how to use static html page instead of resolving `500` error with `_error.tsx`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Sitecore document, If you cannot find the `Error Handling section`, you might have forgotten to select the Error Handling option when creating your site collection.

So you need to check that.

Refer to this document for more details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/generate-a-custom-static-error-page.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am able to see the section in item but "Server error page link" is inactive as per document. So i was looking if there is any way, we can handle error pages from static html instead of rendering host. Thanks.